# Why does google map not work in emulator but works in a real Android device?

Tags: android, google-maps, emulation, device

Hi i have created a google map where my google map is working in my mobile but the same google map does not work in an emulator. It says "my app has stopped working" and tells me to update google play services. How am i supposed to do that in an emulator? Just as i go to press on update in emulator it says app has unfornately stopped? Any suggestions?

Comment: what emulator you are using

Comment: Try to use your android emulator with target version (Google API) support inorder to use Google maps

Comment: @khushi: try Android x.x with google apis emulator

Comment: @lazyPA: i am using nexus4 API 23

Comment: @Learner: i am using nexus4 API 23

Comment: How do i do that?@kevz: i am using nexus4 API 23

Comment: @khushi Please check my answer and it will work :)

Comment: Use genymotion emulator and add play services .

Answer (score 0):

First check and install Google API's

[image: one]

Now Create new virtual device

[image: two]

Select Ur device here ... For your Nexus 4

[image: three]

For google maps and all your google play services you need to create

With Google API (Which support google play services)

[image: four]

NEXT -> Finish

specify ur emuator name and its configuration using Advanced Setttings. then click Finish

Finally run your project application using this created Emulator .. It works